# Нужны здесь запятые или нет?

Tags: запятые

«Администрация Кировского поселения согласовывает установку биотуалета для обслуживающего персонала и гарантирует вывоз стоков».

Answer (score 2):

Категорически нет, ни одной.

Администрация согласовывает и гарантирует (подлежащее, два однородных сказуемых с одиночным соединительным союзом),

остальное - дополнения, определения и обстоятельства, ничем не осложнённые.